# how to test Bootstrap Modal in AngularJS using jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, karma-jasmine

I am using bootstrap modal for displaying pop up's in angular app. It is working perfectly from front end but DOM elements inside pop up are not getting appended to the body

In the output, when I am displaying content of document, content of my html template is not getting appended to body tag. So I am unable to find/test any DOM element. It is not displaying any errors in console also.

Please any one can help me in resolving this issue by specifying how to test bootstrap modal in angular application using karma/jasmine.

```
angular.module("myApp").directive('popUp', ['$http', '$compile', function($http, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            course: '=',
    },
    compile: function(element, cAtts){
        var template,
            $element,
            loader;

        var windowOpen = false;

        loader = $http.get('components/popUp.view.html').success(function(data) {
            template = data;
        });

        //return the Link function
        return function(scope, element, lAtts) {

            element.on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $element = $( $compile(template)(scope) ); 
                $element.modal({backdrop: 'static'});
                windowOpen = true;
            });

            // if the template changes, we need to compile the current
            // template again.  just in case there are funky sticky things
            scope.$watch('template', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if(newValue == undefined && oldValue == undefined) return;
                if(windowOpen) return;

                if(newValue == undefined){
                    //$(".modal").remove();
                    $element.remove();
                    $element = undefined;
                    return;
                }

                $element = $( $compile(template)(scope) );
            }); 
        };
    }
  }    

}]);
```

My HTML Template:

```
    <div id="{{handler}}" class="modal fade">
      <div style="margin:-1px auto; width:90%;float:right;" class="modal-dialog">
        <div style="padding-left: 25px; height:100vh;" class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header navbar-static-top"><img src="content/assets/img/close.png" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="close()" title="Close" alt="Close" class="popUpClose close pull-left"/>
            <div class="popUpTitle">
              <div style="font-size:22px;">{{course.CourseName}}</div>
              <div style="font-size:15px; margin-top:-5px;">{{course.CourseId}}</div><br/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style="display:inline" class="modal-body">
            <p>This is test Modal</p>
          </div>
          <div style="border:none;" class="modal-footer"> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My Test File:

```
(function(){
    "use strict";
    describe("Testing Pop Up Directive Functionality", function(){
        var $httpBackend, $scope, fakeData, $compile, $document;
        var compileDirective, course, element, template;

        beforeEach(module('myApp.testing'));
        beforeEach(module('myApp'));

        beforeEach(inject(function ($injector, _$templateCache_, _$httpBackend_, _fakeData_, _$document_) {
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            fakeData = _fakeData_;
            $document = _$document_;

            angular.module('components/popUp.view.html')._runBlocks[0](_$templateCache_);
            template = _$templateCache_.get('components/courses/course.attendance.popUp.view.html');

            course = fakeData.fakeCourses.Courses[0];

            compileDirective = function() {
                inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {                 
                    $compile = _$compile_;
                    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
                    $scope.course=course;
                    element = angular.element('<div manageattendance="" course="course"></div>');
                    element = $compile(element)($scope);
                });

                //$scope.$digest();
            };
        }));

        it("Should display attendance of course if user is authorized", function(){
            $httpBackend.expectGET('components/courses/course.attendance.popUp.view.html').respond(template);
            compileDirective();         
            $httpBackend.flush();
            element.trigger('click');
            console.log($document.find('html').html());
        });
    });
})();
```

AngularJS : 1.3.11
Bootstrap : 3.3.2
Karma     : 0.12.31
Jasmine-core : 2.3.4
karma-jasmine : 0.3.5

Comment: Did you consider using **[angular-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)**, instead of creating directive counter-parts for each bootstrap components?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the cause but by removing css class "fade" from modal div, html content from modal is getting appended to the body tag.